# Check Validity of a Zip File

Tags: delphi

When I try to check the validity of a zip file an exception is raised that the process can not access the file because it is being used by another process, yet the code in Open1.Click opens the zip file with no problem.  Is there something wrong in Valid1Click?

```
procedure TForm1.Valid1Click(Sender: TObject);
{ Is the zip file valid. }
var
  iZipFile: TZipFile;
  iZipFilename: string;
  iValid: Boolean;
begin
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  try
    { Create the TZipFile Class }
    iZipFile := TZipFile.Create;
    try
      if FileExists(ZipFilename1.Text) then
      begin
         iZipFilename := ZipFilename1.Text;
         { Open zip file for reading }
         iZipFile.Open(iZipFilename, zmRead);
         iValid := iZipFile.IsValid(iZipFilename);
         if iValid then
           MessageBox(0, 'The zip file is valid.', 'Check Zip File',
             MB_ICONINFORMATION or MB_OK)
         else
           MessageBox(0, 'The zip file is NOT valid.', 'Check Zip File',
              MB_ICONWARNING or MB_OK);
         end
         else
            begin
              MessageBox(0, 'The zip file does not exist.', 'Warning',
                MB_ICONWARNING or MB_OK);
            end;
         { Close the zip file }
         iZipFile.Close;
       finally
         iZipFile.Free;
       end;
     finally
        Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
     end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Open1Click(Sender: TObject);
{ Open zip file. }
var
  i: integer;
  iZipFile: TZipFile;
  iFilename: string;
  iDateTime: TDateTime;
  iCompressedSize: cardinal;
  iUnCompressedSize: cardinal;
  iCRC32: cardinal;
  iCompressionMethod: word;
  iFileComment: string;
  iListItem: TlistItem;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    if FileExists(OpenDialog1.FileName) then
    begin
      iZipFile := TZipFile.Create;
      try
        ListView1.Items.Clear;
        ZipFilename1.Text := OpenDialog1.FileName;
        try
          iZipFile.Open(ZipFilename1.Text, zmReadWrite);
          for i := 0 to iZipFile.FileCount - 1 do
          begin
            iFilename := iZipFile.FileNames[i];
            iListItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
            iListItem.Caption := iFilename;
            iDateTime := FileDateToDateTime
              (iZipFile.FileInfo[i].ModifiedDateTime);
            iListItem.SubItems.Add(DateTimeToStr(iDateTime)); { 0 }
            iCompressedSize := iZipFile.FileInfo[i].CompressedSize;
            iListItem.SubItems.Add(FormatByteSize(iCompressedSize)); { 1 }
            iUnCompressedSize := iZipFile.FileInfo[i].UncompressedSize;
            iListItem.SubItems.Add(FormatByteSize(iUnCompressedSize)); { 2 }
            iCRC32 := iZipFile.FileInfo[i].CRC32;
            iListItem.SubItems.Add(IntToStr(iCRC32)); { 3 }
            iCompressionMethod := iZipFile.FileInfo[i].CompressionMethod;
            iListItem.SubItems.Add
              (ZipCompressionToStr(iCompressionMethod)); { 4 }
            iFileComment := iZipFile.Comment;
            iListItem.SubItems.Add(iFileComment); { 5 }
          end;
          iZipFile.Close;
        except
          on E: Exception do
          begin
            ShowMessage(E.ClassName + #10#13 + E.Message);
          end;
        end;
      finally
        iZipFile.Free;
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have these lines the wrong way round:

```
iZipFile.Open(iZipFilename, zmRead);
iValid := iZipFile.IsValid(iZipFilename);
```

The first line locks the file, and so the second line fails. You will have to call `IsValid` before calling `Open`.

Having said that, since you use `zmRead`, it should be possible for the call to `IsValid` to open the file again because the call to `Open` used `fmOpenRead`. So I suspect that there may be a bug in the ZIP file code, or the file stream code, in the version of Delphi that you are using. All the same, calling `IsValid` before `Open` is sure to work.

In fact, `IsValid` is a class method. You should call it like this:

```
iValid := TZipFile.IsValid(iZipFilename);
```

It comes to the same thing in the end, but it makes it clear to the reader of the code that the method call does not rely on the state of an instance.

In fact I personally would simply do away with the call to `IsValid` and go straight to calling `Open`. If that fails, I believe that a meaningful error message will be raised.

---

**Update**

Looks like you don't want to open the file at all, and just want to check its validity. In which case, you don't need an instance, you don't call the constructor, and you just use a single call to `TZipFile.IsValid`.

```
procedure TForm1.Valid1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  try
    if FileExists(ZipFilename1.Text) then
    begin
      if TZipFile.IsValid(ZipFilename1.Text) then
        ...
  finally
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It is beginning to look like open is not even needed at all and maybe even iZipFile := TZipFile.Create;?

Comment: Ah, I assumed that you wanted to read the file. If you only want to check validity then you don't need an instance at all.

Answer (score 0):

As David Heffernan stated initially : it should be possible to use isValid after TZipFile::Open(filename, mode), since one would expect opening a file read only would not block it for others to read.

When using the Open-method based on a fileNAME (another one exists for reading f from a TFileStream), it internally creates a fileStream, and while it *does* specify fmOpenRead, it *does not* set a share mode on opening this stream.

See this blog post for an example on how this can be avoided by first creating a TFileStream yourself in which you specify the share mode explicitly :
https://www.digon.be/community/blog/TZipFile-problem-accessing-open-files-even-with-TZipMode-zmRead